# Application doesn't detect Vidyo plugin/registry key(?) when run as administrator

Tags: wpf, windows, administrator, registrykey, vidyo

I have a WPF application (let's call it Test.exe) which launches a WebBrowser control which needs to run in IE11 mode as it uses a VidyoWeb plugin installed on my host machine which requires IE11.

I have added an entry to the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry key (in `SOFTWARE/WOW6432Node/Microsoft/InternetExplorer/Main/FeatureControl` since the application is 32-bit) as follows:

```
Name: Test.exe
Type: REG_DWORD
Value (decimal): 11001
```

When the application is *not* launched as an administrator then the plugin loads no problem. However when I run as admin the plugin isn't detected. I have no idea why the plugin wouldn't be detected when running with more privileges.

I am running the release exe of the application, not debugging using Visual Studio.

Comment: Curious, why are you running the app as admin?

Comment: I was testing running as admin because the application loading the WebBrowser control isn't owned by me so I don't know if they will be running as admin or not.

Answer (score 1):

Typically on windows the installer performs a per user installation of per machine installation depending on the access privileges of the user. It sounds like you installed the plugin for that user account.  Try installing the plugin from the admin account.